# Can a minor (3 year old) apply for UK Tier-2 Dependent visa alone?

Tags: united-kingdom

I want first to apply for UK Tier-2 general visa for myself.After travelling to UK and settled comfortably (assuming 3 or 4 months later), will apply for my 3 year old daughter's dependent visa. Is this allowed?? or as she is a minor,I should apply for her visa together with my application? Someone told me we should apply to minor's visa together with parents and minors can not apply alone even I submit all supporting documents. I am looking for a expert answer. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Technically every visa is an individual application. If you receive your Tier 2 visa, the dependent visa can be applied for at anytime afterwords.

Comment: That sounds plausible (although I wouldn't put anything past the Home Office), but do you have any official sources to back it up?